# Error - JSX Element type 'X'does not have any constructor or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, tsx

I am trying to render a data by context provider however i got this message reading JSX Element type Context does not have any constructor or call signatures.

My Code in App.tsx is

```
import { Context } from './interfaces/cardContext';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Context>
          <RestaurantDetails />
        </Context>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App
```

and in my Context page

```
export interface ContextData {
  restaurants: restaurantType[];
}
export interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
export const Context = createContext({} as ContextData);

export const Provider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState<restaurantType[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5001/restaurants')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setRestaurants(data));
  }, []);
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ restaurants }}>{children}</Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: `import { Context } from './interfaces/cardContext';` Did you mean to `import { Provider }` instead? If Context is correct, then you can't render `<Context>` since that's not a component. The components are `<Context.Provider>` or `<Context.Consumer>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import your provider as a wrapper of other components:

```js
import { Provider } from './interfaces/cardContext';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Provider>
          <RestaurantDetails />
        </Provider>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App
```

And then use your context like this in other componens:

```js
import {useContext} from 'react';
import { Context } from 'path-to-card-context';
```

```js
const {restaurants} = useContext(Context);
```